# Is there any way i can rank student score in sql php?

Tags: mysql

table_result

```
regno      fullname     total     rankno
5780       sunday       90
5781       joy          100  
5782       emma         70
5783       samuel       80
5784       faith        80
```

expected result

```
regno     fullname    total     rankno
5781      joy         100        1
5780       sunday     90         2
5783       samuel     80         3
5784       faith      80         3
```

Comment: seems like `ORDER BY total DESC` would suit your needs?

Comment: `Select * from your_table order by total  desc;`

Comment: The answer to your question depends on your MySQL version. v8+, you can use the RANK() stuff (Windowing functions). Pre v8, you need to use @session variables. The linked question has answers showing both approaches.